# tapfortap banner doesn't shown if required from code

Tags: android, adview

If I put this in my activity layout than the banner is shown with no problems

```
<com.tapfortap.AdView android:id="@+id/ad_view"
  android:layout_height="50dip"
  android:layout_width="320dip"
  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
  />
```

But id I do this in code my banner is not shown

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
// Optionally specify layout params.
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = (int)(50 * (width / 320.0));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
adView.setLayoutParams(myLayoutParams);
// Add the AdView to your layout.
myLayout.addView(adView);
```

the problem is

> 10-19 13:04:02.066 W/com.tapfortap.AdView(15940): Unable to display
>   ads, not enough space.

I do not understand because mylayout have more than enough space in this sample app I am creating is the only one in the whole screen

Answer (score 1):

There is problems when you using  padding , even if it is just the top padding and there is a lot of space...

maybe this will be solved with the next versions of tapfortap sdk

Answer (score 0):

The Tap for Tap SDK no longer checks for enough space to display ads, that is up to developers now.